# Inclusion of orthogonal complements: if $U_1\subset\ U_2$, then $U_2^\bot\subset\ U_1^\bot$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Show if $U_1\subset\ U_2$, then $U_2^\bot\subset\ U_1^\bot$

I'm thinking using contradiction. 
$\exists v\in U_2^\bot$ s.t. $v\notin U_1^\bot$ $\Rightarrow$ $\exists u\in U_1$ s.t. $u\notin U_2$

Let $v\in U_2^\bot$ and $v\notin U_1^\bot$, then $\exists u_2\in U_2$ s.t. $\lt v,u_2\gt =0$ and $\forall u_1 \in U_1, \lt v,u_1\gt \neq 0$

This implies, $\forall u_1 \in U_1, u_1\neq u_2$. Hence, $U_1\not\subset U_2$

I feel like this should be really easy with direct proof, but I keep getting $U_1^\bot = U_2^\bot$. What am I doing wrong?

Any hint will be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that there's no need to use contradiction here (although what you were trying is really contraposition.) Here's the direct proof, where by $v\perp u$ I mean $\langle v,u\rangle=0$.

Assume $U_1\subset U_2$ and $v\in U^\perp_2$. Then $v\perp u$ for all $u\in U_2$.
If $u'\in U_1,$ then in particular $u'\in U_2$ and $v\perp u'.$ Thus $v\perp u'$ for all
$u'\in U_1,$ so $v\in U^\perp_1,$ and we've shown $v\in U^\perp_2\Rightarrow v\in U^\perp_1$,
i.e. $U_2^\perp\subset U_1^\perp$.